# privilege issue on procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have created procedure like below :

> CREATE DEFINER=`ftdinc`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_all_dates`(
>   in_product_id           varchar(100),    in_zip_code
>   varchar(100),    in_max_delivery_date    DateTime) .......etc.
>
> call pas.get_all_dates('FK35', '10001','2013-09-09 00:00:00'); ERROR
>   1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'pas'@'%' for table
>   'pas.get_all_dates'

Actually we don't have the user pas. We have only ftdinc user.

why it was executing with pas user innstead of ftdinc user.we are not understood.

Please help me

Comment: @stephen not getting results.SELECT command denied to user 'pas'@'%'   we have ftdinc user and ftddefiner.why it was executing with pas user i dont know.

Comment: try `call ftdinc.get_all_dates('FK35', '10001','2013-09-09 00:00:00'); `

Comment: actually we have database with name pas.in that we have stored procedure 'get_all_dates'.so iam calling pas.get_all_dates('FK35', '10001','2013-09-09 00:00:00');

Comment: i see then the key question is with what user do you exec the `call` ? because from the error is user `pas`

Answer (score 0):

Using the info from the error you are trying to `call` the procedure using the user `pas` which doesn't have rights so the easiest solution but not very safe is :

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'pas'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You have 2 choices:

1) grant the rights to user `pas`
2) use user `ftdinc` to execute the call

Comment: previously we dont have pas user it works fine. but now it was looking for pas user.

Comment: did you executed the `grant` and `flush` ?